# Compile Java package in CMD

Tags: java, class, cmd

i have a java application done in netbeans, and it has a package called my.alarm and it has an interface class called AlarmListener.java, an GUI class called AlarmGUI.java and a another class called Alarm.java which has all the methods implemented. so i would like to compile this package in command line instead of using netbeans. How do i do that ? the class paths were set and jdk was properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

In Cmd line issue the following command

```
javac -d . *.java
```

make sure javac is in your path.

Comment: javac -d . *.java is not recognized i suppose, says :- javac: file not found: *.java

Answer (score 0):

Since all your classes and dependencies resides in your only package, You could use something from your package directory like:

```
javac *.java
```

You could check the usage of javac (java compiler) and use as per your need further in addition to above:

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
-g                         Generate all debugging info
-g:none                    Generate no debugging info
-g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
-nowarn                    Generate no warnings
-verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
-deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
-classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
-cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
-sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
-bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
-extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
-endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
-proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
-processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...]Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
-processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
-d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
-s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
-implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
-encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
-source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
-target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
-version                   Version information
-help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
-Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
-X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
-J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```